# How to deploy multi-module war using jenkins

Tags: deployment, war, jenkins-plugins, using

I am using jenkins to build war. I have two modules and I am using parent pom to build war and that builds war successfully but in job I can deploy only one war at a time using deploy plugin.

How can I deploy my two modules at a time when build success using jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use wildcards?
i'm using the websphere deployment plugin and i use wildcards:
for example: `modules/**/lastSuccessful/**/*.war`